# image slider doesn't work using route in angular js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

I'm newbie to Angular js..But try to make an image slider in my file..

And also I'm using route..Acutally I'm having three pages..

**1.home**
**2.about**
**3.contact**

For this I create an `index` file in which I add header and footer

While I'm adding the slider in my `index` page it works fine for me..

But if I did the same thing in my **`home`** page..It won't work and I din't find any errors in my console also..

I don't know how to fix it..

Here I attach my all codes..

**script.js**

```
// create the module and name it scotchApp
var scotchApp = angular.module('scotchApp', ['ngRoute','ngAnimate', 'ngTouch']);

// configure our routes
scotchApp.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        // route for the home page
        .when('/', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
            controller  : 'homeController'
        })

        // route for the about page
        .when('/about', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/about.html',
            controller  : 'aboutController'
        })

        // route for the contact page
        .when('/contact', {
            templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
            controller  : 'contactController'
        });
});

// create the controller and inject Angular's $scope
scotchApp.controller('mainController', function($scope) {

    //Logo
    $scope.logo = 'logo.png';

    //username
    $scope.username = 'Jonathan Stephanopalus';

    //footercontent
    $scope.footer = [
        { title: 'Contacts' },
        { title: 'Feedback' },
        { title: 'Help' },
        { title: 'Site Map' },
        { title: 'Terms & Conditions' },
        { title: 'Privacy Statement' },
        { title: 'Cookie Policy' },
        { title: 'Trademarks' }

    ];

});

scotchApp.controller('homeController', function($scope) {

    // create a message to display in our view
    $scope.message = "Lorem Ipsum ";
    //lastdiv
    $scope.lastdiv = { image : "women_wright.png" ,title:"Get to know Cisco better: Community Forums"};

    //slider
    $scope.slides = [
        {image: 'images/img00.jpg', description: 'Image 00'},
        {image: 'images/img01.jpg', description: 'Image 01'},
        {image: 'images/img02.jpg', description: 'Image 02'},
        {image: 'images/img03.jpg', description: 'Image 03'},
        {image: 'images/img04.jpg', description: 'Image 04'}
    ];

    $scope.direction = 'left';
    $scope.currentIndex = 0;

    $scope.setCurrentSlideIndex = function (index) {
        $scope.direction = (index > $scope.currentIndex) ? 'left' : 'right';
        $scope.currentIndex = index;
    };

    $scope.isCurrentSlideIndex = function (index) {
        return $scope.currentIndex === index;
    };

    $scope.prevSlide = function () {
        $scope.direction = 'left';
        $scope.currentIndex = ($scope.currentIndex < $scope.slides.length - 1) ? ++$scope.currentIndex : 0;
    };

    $scope.nextSlide = function () {
        $scope.direction = 'right';
        $scope.currentIndex = ($scope.currentIndex > 0) ? --$scope.currentIndex : $scope.slides.length - 1;
    };

});

scotchApp.animation('.slide-animation', function () {
    return {
        beforeAddClass: function (element, className, done) {
            var scope = element.scope();

            if (className == 'ng-hide') {
                var finishPoint = element.parent().width();
                if(scope.direction !== 'right') {
                    finishPoint = -finishPoint;
                }
                TweenMax.to(element, 0.5, {left: finishPoint, onComplete: done });
            }
            else {
                done();
            }
        },
        removeClass: function (element, className, done) {
            var scope = element.scope();

            if (className == 'ng-hide') {
                element.removeClass('ng-hide');

                var startPoint = element.parent().width();
                if(scope.direction === 'right') {
                    startPoint = -startPoint;
                }

                TweenMax.fromTo(element, 0.5, { left: startPoint }, {left: 0, onComplete: done });
            }
            else {
                done();
            }
        }
    };
});

scotchApp.controller('aboutController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Look! I am an about page.';
});

scotchApp.controller('contactController', function($scope) {
    $scope.message = 'Contact us! JK. This is just a demo.';
});
```

**home.html**

```
<div ng-controller="homeController">
    <div class="container slider">
        <img  ng-repeat="slide in slides" class="slide slide-animation nonDraggableImage" ng-swipe-right="nextSlide()" ng-swipe-left="prevSlide()" ng-hide="!isCurrentSlideIndex($index)" ng-src="{{slide.image}}">
        <a class="arrow prev" href="#" ng-click="nextSlide()"></a>
        <a class="arrow next" href="#" ng-click="prevSlide()"></a>
        <nav class="nav">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <ul class="dots">
                    <li class="dot" ng-repeat="slide in slides">
                        <a href="#" ng-class="{'active':isCurrentSlideIndex($index)}" ng-click="setCurrentSlideIndex($index);">{{slide.description}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
        test
    </div>
</div>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<!-- define angular app -->
<html ng-app="scotchApp">

<head>
      <!-- SCROLLS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <!-- <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main.css" /> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.0/css/font-awesome.css" />
    <!-- <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <!-- <script src="js/app.js"></script> -->

      <!-- SPELLS -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular-touch.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.10.3/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
      <!-- <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular.min.js"></script> -->
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.25/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<!-- define angular controller -->
<body class="angular_class" ng-controller="mainController">

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="menu_1">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><img src="image/{{logo}}"></a>
        </div>
        <div class="f_right">
          <p>Welcome, {{ username }}</p>
          <img src="image/sml_logo.png">
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="menu_1">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left">
          <li ng-repeat="teams in teamArray"><a href="#{{ teams.link }}">{{ teams.team_name }}</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="f_right">
          <input type="text" class="searchbox" placeholder="Search"></input>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="main">

    <!-- angular templating -->
        <!-- this is where content will be injected -->
    <div ng-view></div>

  </div>

  <footer class="text-center">
    <div class="footer_block">
      <span ng-repeat="ft in footer"><a href="">{{ ft.title }}</a></span>
    </div>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

And for information I follow this [link](http://onehungrymind.com/build-sweet-photo-slider-angularjs-animate/)

Could someone please help me out of this..

Thank you,

Comment: What means it won't work? What is the exactly behaviour?

Comment: It mean it show me the images in home page but when I click the prev and next arrow icons it doesn't slide and show me the next image

Answer (score 0):

Change home.html

```
<div ng-controller="homeController">
<div class="container slider">
    <img  ng-repeat="slide in slides" class="slide slide-animation nonDraggableImage" ng-swipe-right="nextSlide()" ng-swipe-left="prevSlide()" ng-hide="!isCurrentSlideIndex($index)" ng-src="{{slide.image}}">
    <a class="arrow prev" href="#" ng-click="nextSlide()"></a>
    <a class="arrow next" href="#" ng-click="prevSlide()"></a>
    <nav class="nav">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul class="dots">
                <li class="dot" ng-repeat="slide in slides">
                    <a href="#" ng-class="{'active':isCurrentSlideIndex($index)}" ng-click="setCurrentSlideIndex($index);">{{slide.description}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    test
</div>
```

with

```
<div class="container slider">
    <img  ng-repeat="slide in slides" class="slide slide-animation nonDraggableImage" ng-swipe-right="nextSlide()" ng-swipe-left="prevSlide()" ng-hide="!isCurrentSlideIndex($index)" ng-src="{{slide.image}}">
    <a class="arrow prev" href="#" ng-click="nextSlide()"></a>
    <a class="arrow next" href="#" ng-click="prevSlide()"></a>
    <nav class="nav">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <ul class="dots">
                <li class="dot" ng-repeat="slide in slides">
                    <a href="#" ng-class="{'active':isCurrentSlideIndex($index)}" ng-click="setCurrentSlideIndex($index);">{{slide.description}}</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
    test
</div>
```

Comment: It shows nothing changes in my slider :(
And I've a doubt without controller it works !!...
Actually my slider appears but I don't know how it retrieve all those values from that controller